# Age range from date of birth in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get age range from date of birth (`DOB`) and group by age to convert the query latter to JPA query

```
 SELECT 
         SUM (CASE WHEN B.id = 1 THEN 1 END)
             AS OPD,
         SUM (CASE WHEN B.id = 2 THEN 1 END)
             AS IPD,
         SUM (CASE WHEN B.id = 3 THEN 1 END)
             AS DC,
         SUM (CASE WHEN B.id = 4 THEN 1 END)
             AS PROC,
         SUM (CASE WHEN B.id = 5 THEN 1 END)
             AS SUR,
         TRUNC ((MONTHS_BETWEEN (TRUNC (SYSDATE), TO_DATE (C.DOB)) / 12))
          As Age,
             CASE
             WHEN AGE <= 5 THEN 'PEDIA 1 (AGE 0-5 Years)'
             WHEN AGE >= 12 THEN 'ADULT'
             ELSE 'PEDIA 2 (AGE 5-12 Years)'
         END
             AS AGE_GROUP,
         SUM (CASE
                  WHEN B.id IN (1, 2, 3,4,5)THEN 1
              END)
             AS Total
    FROM TRANSACTIONS A,
         VISIT       B,
         PATIENTS C
   WHERE     A.TYPE = B.id
         AND A.CODE_ONE = 5654
         AND A.PATIENTID = C.PATIENTID
         AND A.CODE_to = 64564
GROUP BY Age
```

I'm getting this error

[image]

I want the result to be like this

[image]

Comment: seeing as this seems strictly sql, why do you tag it 'java' and 'spring-boot'?

Comment: @Stultuske I'm trying first to write as sql then I will convert it as JPA

Comment: So, at this point, it is strictly sql. Keep the tags to what it is now, that 'll make it more clear for us what to focus on. At this point, it has nothing to do with Java or JPA, just with sql

Comment: You can't use aliases and use them right away in your query. So you can't group by "Age", but you can group by "TRUNC ((MONTHS_BETWEEN (TRUNC (SYSDATE), TO_DATE (C.DOB)) / 12))". Same goes for using Age in the definition of AGE_GROUP.  Try using subqueries.

Comment: @VincentvanderLinden sorry I didn't understand you how can i do it as subqueries, I tried to group by "TRUNC ((MONTHS_BETWEEN (TRUNC (SYSDATE), TO_DATE (C.DOB)) / 12))" but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

There's no predefined column called `age` but `dob` within the table `patients`, then whether individually replace each `age` with `TRUNC( MONTHS_BETWEEN( sysdate, dob ) / 12 )` function or put this conversion into a subquery which selects from `patients` table while aliasing `age` as in the following one

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN age <= 5 THEN
          'PEDIA 1 (AGE 0-5 Years)'
         WHEN age >= 12 THEN
          'ADULT'
         ELSE
          'PEDIA 2 (AGE 5-12 Years)'
       END AS age_group,
       SUM(CASE WHEN v.id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS opd,
       SUM(CASE WHEN v.id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS ipd,
       SUM(CASE WHEN v.id = 3 THEN 1 END) AS daycare,
       SUM(CASE WHEN v.id = 4 THEN 1 END) AS proc,
       SUM(CASE WHEN v.id = 5 THEN 1 END) AS surgery,
       SUM(CASE WHEN v.id BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 END) AS total
  FROM transactions t
  JOIN visit v 
    ON v.id = t.type
  JOIN ( SELECT p.*, 
                TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate,TO_DATE(dob,'yyyy-mm-dd')) / 12) AS age  
           FROM patients p ) p
    ON p.patientid = t.patientid
 WHERE t.code_one = 5654
   AND t.code_to = 64564
 GROUP BY age
```

assuming the `dob` column, which is a *non-date* type column, while *this is not recommended*, has a *fixed format of `yyyy-mm-dd`* throughout the table.

Comment: Still it doesn't group them by age

Comment: realised that I missed `TO_DATE` conversion, why? is that a string type field ? then can you tell me the sample format for the dob values? Btw, it's recommended to hold a date value within a date type column @Hamda